# Rails Webpacker does not compile subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ecmascript-6, compilation, webpacker

EDIT: **Solution:** *make sure you spell the class-methods correctly*. My error stemmed from typing `contructor()` within the class (please refer to the source-code of `SocialShareModal.js`.

Also, *make sure your linter in your editor of choice works correctly*! Mine did not. It would have spared me hours if it actually did :-)

---

I am running a Rails-application (ruby v `2.6.2` / Rails v `6.0.2`) using webpacker. My JavaScript has been working like a charm, up until I tried putting component-related JS into a dedicated sub-directory of my `app/javascript`-folder.

This is what my JS-file-tree looks like:

```
javascript
├──channels
├──custom
│  ├──components (new & not working)
│  ├──config
│  ├──helpers (these are working somehow)
│  └──pages
├──config
└──packs
```

In `application.js` I import a custom `Router.js`, initialize it with my custom routes to then, on various subpages, initialize my custom JS-classes. It all worked so far (and continues to) with classes which live in the `helpers`-folder, however the classes which live in the new `components`-folder won't work. I am unsure if they are even picked up and compiled by webpack.

`application.js`:

```
import routes from '../custom/config/routes'
import Router from '../custom/Router'

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require('channels')

...

class myApp {
  constructor() {
    this._initRouter()
  }

  /**
   * Initializes the router and its routes
   * @private
   */
  _initRouter () {
    this._router = new Router(routes)
  }
}

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {
  window.myApp = new myApp()
})
```

`routes.js`:

```
import Page from '../pages/page'

// Frontend
import Root from '../pages/frontend/root'
import SignInPage from '../pages/frontend/signInPage'

// Dashboard => Admin
import AdminAccountsEditPage from '../pages/dashboard/admin/accounts/edit'

// Dashboard => User
import WelcomePage from '../pages/dashboard/user/welcomePage'

export default [
  // Frontend
  ['', Root],
  ['accounts/sign_in', SignInPage],

  // Dashboard => Admin
  ['admin/accounts/(.*)', AdminAccountsEditPage],

  // Dashboard => User
  ['dashboard/willkommen', WelcomePage],

  // Catch all for when there is no exact match:
  ['(.*)', Page]
]
```

`Router.js`:

```
/* global location */
export default class Router {
  constructor(routes) {
    this.routes = routes
    this.handleRoute()
  }

  /**
   * Checks if there's a javascript for the current route, requires the class and
   * instantiates it
   * @private
   */
  handleRoute() {
    let { pathname } = location

    // Remove leading and trailing slashes
    pathname = pathname.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '')

    // Go through routes and check which one matches
    for (let i = 0; i < this.routes.length; i++) {
      const [route, PageClass] = this.routes[i]

      const regexp = new RegExp(`^${route}$`, 'i')
      if (route === true || regexp.test(pathname)) {
        this.currentPage = new PageClass()

        break
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`Page.js`:

```
import tippy from 'tippy.js'
import 'tippy.js/dist/tippy.css'

import FlashMessageHelper from '../helpers/FlashMessageHelper'
import AddToWishlistHelper from '../helpers/AddToWishlistHelper'
import SocialShareModal from '../components/SocialShareModal' // importing it

export default class Page {
  constructor() {
    new tippy('[data-tippy-content]')
    new FlashMessageHelper() // working
    new AddToWishlistHelper() // working
    new SocialShareModal() // NOT working (not initializing)
  }
}
```

`SocialShareModal.js`

```
export default class SocialShareModal {
  get modalSelector() { return '.modal' }
  get triggerModalSelector() { return '.js-trigger-modal' }
  get copyToClipBoardButtonSelector() { return '.js-copy-to-clipboard' }

  contructor() { // As you can see, the error resided here
    console.log('SocialShareModal constructor called')
    this.init()
  }

  init() {
    let modalButton = document.querySelector(this.triggerModalSelector)
    modal.addEventListener('click', handleModalTrigger)
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleTestScroll)
  }

  handleModalTrigger() {
    let modal = document.querySelector(this.modalSelector)
    modal.classList.add('is-active')
  }
}
```

I've done lots of reading, but can't seem to figure out the issue, as I'm not super-comfortable with webpack. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Edit: added source-code for `application.js`, `routes.js`, `Router.js`, `Page.js` & `SocialShareModal.js` to provide more context.

Comment: It’s hard to see what the issue is. What is the error? What is the source code?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @rossta, I updated the original post and added some more relevant code.

There is no real "error" when trying to load component-based-JS via a page, it's just that it's never initialized.

Comment: What do you mean by “not initializing”? Is SocialShareModal undefined or is it some other error? Since that file is giving you trouble, it’d be helpful to see its source.

Comment: Hey @rossta, thanks for touching on that subject again. I found my error in the meantime. It stemmed from a simple typo. I can't believe I missed that => I spelled `constructor()` wrong. Simple as that. What really bugs me is that my editor didn't care to highlight that. Thanks for your time!